# why does redux need to make a copy of the data each time it changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, copy, redux, react-redux

From what I've read, redux uses `Object.assign` or the spread operator to make a shallow copy of the data, but how does that make sense? I thought the whole point of it was to make a deep copy of the data that is dispatched so that if the data is changed outside the store, it won't change what's in the store also. if it were a shallow copy, then the data would be linked, which causes issues with the data changing what's in the store even without a dispatch, correct?

In the example below, if action.data were only shallowly copied, then if that data were changed from wherever it came from, it would change what's in the store, even without the dispatch right?

```
const activePokemon = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ACTIVE_POKEMON':
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.data
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: i would check this page out! https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html it talks about immutability and how react works with copies of the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following the [Three Principles](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html) of `redux`, then you won't worry about changes outside the store.

> The only way to change the state is to emit an [action](http://redux.js.org/docs/Glossary.html#action), an object describing what happened.

If the changes outside the store are intended to modify the state, `dispatch` should be used instead. In addition to update of the state, `dispatch` also notifies every subscriber of the store about the changes.

And once you 'linked' some data to the state, the data should not be changed, since it is a part of the state, and..

> State is read-only

Edit: about making a copy

In the documentation of [reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html)(read it again for details!), `redux` only requires our reducers to **stay [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)**. If the new state is different, the reducer must create new object, and making a copy is a way to describe the unchanged part.

We are not always making a copy to describe the new state. `return {}` can be used to clear all state properties, when there are only a few properties to keep, we can specify unchanged properties instead of copying:

```
return {
  unchangedProp0: state.unchangedProp0,
  unchangedProp1: state.unchangedProp1,
  ...newData
}
```

Comment: that's my question, state is read-only, but we're essentially updating it in the reducer by making a copy of the original with updates. why do we have to do that? why do we have to make a copy when we can just replace the whole thing with new data?

Comment: Extended the answer for that